# How can i merge multiple associative arrays by a unique username

Tags: php, arrays

I need to merge 3 associative arrays into a single associative array with unique usernames

My 3 arrays look like this: (var_export)

acceptedArray
`array ( 'user1' => 1, 'user2' => 1, 'user3' => 1, )`

pendingArray
`array ( 'user1' => 1, 'user3' => 2, 'user15' => 3, )`

deniedArray
`array ( 'user1' => 1, 'user15' => 22, 'user20' => 5, )`

every array is a array_count_values of a query fetch.

i need to have an output like this:

```
$return = [
    ['username' => user1, 'accepted' => 1, 'pending' => 3 , 'denied' => 1]
    ['username' => user2, 'accepted' => 1, 'pending' => 4]
];
```

i tried this (yes, completely off):

```
foreach ($acceptedUsers as $key => $value) {
    $return[] = array('username' => $key, 'accepted' => $value);
}
foreach ($pendingUsers as $key => $value) {
    $return[] = array('username' => $key, 'pending' => $value);
}
```

but that's creating duplicates and not appending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate individual arrays and use the usernames as keys for grouping.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NJUvf))

```
$acceptedUsers = ["user1" => 1, "user2" => 1, "user3" => 1];

$pendingUsers = ["user1" => 3, "user2" => 4, "user5" => 2];

$deniedUsers = ["user1" => 1, "user15" => 4, "user10" => 2];

foreach ($acceptedUsers as $user => $count) {
    $result[$user]['accepted'] = $count;
}
foreach ($pendingUsers as $user => $count) {
    $result[$user]['pending'] = $count;
}

foreach ($deniedUsers as $user => $count) {
    $result[$user]['denied'] = $count;
}

var_export($result);
```

And if you need the username inside the subarrays, it's probably less convoluted to just loop the groups once more. https://3v4l.org/0rUv5

```
foreach ($acceptedUsers as $user => $count) {
    $grouped[$user]['accepted'] = $count;
}
foreach ($pendingUsers as $user => $count) {
    $grouped[$user]['pending'] = $count;
}

foreach ($deniedUsers as $user => $count) {
    $grouped[$user]['denied'] = $count;
}

foreach ($grouped as $user => $row) {
    $result[] = ['username' => $user] + $row;
}
var_export($result);
```

Otherwise, make `isset()` checks in loop 2 and 3.  https://3v4l.org/3sstg

```
foreach ($acceptedUsers as $user => $count) {
    $grouped[$user]['username'] = $user;
    $grouped[$user]['accepted'] = $count;
}
foreach ($pendingUsers as $user => $count) {
    if (!isset($grouped[$user])) {
        $grouped[$user]['username'] = $user;
    }
    $grouped[$user]['pending'] = $count;
}

foreach ($deniedUsers as $user => $count) {
    if (!isset($grouped[$user])) {
        $grouped[$user]['username'] = $user;
    }
    $grouped[$user]['denied'] = $count;
}

var_export(array_values($grouped));
```

or brutal-force the usernames (unconditionally overwrite pre-existing username elements) https://3v4l.org/I1kBu

```
foreach ($acceptedUsers as $user => $count) {
    $grouped[$user]['username'] = $user;
    $grouped[$user]['accepted'] = $count;
}
foreach ($pendingUsers as $user => $count) {
    $grouped[$user]['username'] = $user;
    $grouped[$user]['pending'] = $count;
}

foreach ($deniedUsers as $user => $count) {
    $grouped[$user]['username'] = $user;
    $grouped[$user]['denied'] = $count;
}

var_export(array_values($grouped));
```

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that part.  I'll edit. (Slow on my phone).

Comment: @Artur shall I bother to write the username inside the subarrays or will your program work just as well with the usernames as keys?

Comment: You can add ` $result[$user]['username'] = $user;` in each foreach loop and add this `array_values($result);` before `var_export($result);` to get the exact output needed

Comment: It works with the 2nd example , but it's not working with the third, but it's def. on the js side. so everything is just fine!

Comment: If the 3rd or 4th snippets aren't working in your project check that your variable names are exactly as in my snippets. @Artur

Comment: You might even perform the counting manually to avoid 3 `array_count_values()` calls.  https://3v4l.org/6cCGQ

Answer (score -3):

You can try this code for getting your result

```
$acceptedArray = array ( 'user1' => 1, 'user2' => 1, 'user3' => 1 );
$pendingArray = array ( 'user1' => 1, 'user3' => 2, 'user15' => 3 );
$deniedArray = array ( 'user1' => 1, 'user15' => 22, 'user20' => 5 );

// Get all distinct username from 3 arrays given 
$u1 = array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($acceptedArray),array_keys($pendingArray),array_keys($deniedArray)));


$result = array(); // Initialize the result array

$index=0;
// Loop through each username and check if he has accept value, pending value and denied value
// If value exist, we assign value from array else set it as 0
foreach($u1 as $key => $val){
    $tmp = array();
    $tmp['username'] = $val;

    if(isset($pendingArray[$val])) 
        $tmp['pending'] = $pendingArray[$val]; 
    else 
        $tmp['pending'] = 0;

    if(isset($acceptedArray[$val])) 
        $tmp['accepted'] = $acceptedArray[$val]; 
    else 
        $tmp['accepted'] = 0;

    if(isset($deniedArray[$val])) 
        $tmp['denied'] = $deniedArray[$val]; 
    else 
        $tmp['denied'] = 0;

    $result[$index] = $tmp;
    $index++;
}
```

Demo link is https://3v4l.org/ZnFuX

Comment: Answers are more likely to be helpful, when you explain your solution.  Lateness is not something to apologize for.  A year from now, when a researcher finds this page, they won't care if an answer was an hour/day/month late.  The only thing that matters is quality.